# R: Multidimensional array index assignment

Tags: r, list, multidimensional-array, indexing

Consider the following array assignments:

```
temp=array(list(),2)
temp[[2]][[2]]=c("a","b")
temp[[1]][[2]]="c"
```

This produces the following result:

```
temp
[[1]]
[1] NA  "c"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

Instead, I want the result to be:

```
temp
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL
[[1]][[2]]
[1] "c"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

How do I make the assignment so that the former is produced rather than the latter?

Comment: Try `list(list(NULL, "c"), list(NULL, c("a", "b")))`

Comment: In my actual code I create the contents of this array using loops and other functions with variable outputs. I can't manually solve the problem in the middle of my function; I need some way to insert the result directly to the proper place in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the list(s) with `replicate` instead of `array`.  Lists and arrays behave differently

```
x <- replicate(2, list())
x[[1]][[2]] <- "c"
x[[2]][[2]] <- c("a", "b")
x
```

Note:

```
is.array(x)
# [1] FALSE
sapply(x, is.array)
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```